# How To Reverse a number like 001 into 100 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Sample Input:    001

Sample Output:   100

I'm Trying something like this but it shouldn't work,can anyone help me.

```
 x = int(input())

 s = str(x)

 s1 = s[::-1]

 print(s1)
```

Comment: Don't use `int()`; just skip that, as you will lose information about the padded zeroes.

Comment: You got useful answers, yet you did not mark any answer as accepted. Please do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By casting the input to an int in your first line with the call to `int()` you are removing the information that there were two leading zeros (in your example). This means that in the second line, calling `str()` is just producing `'1'` instead of `'001'` because that information was destroyed in the casting process.

The solution is to not cast the input, and instead keep it as a string, removing the call to `int()`

```
s=input()
s1=s[::-1]
print(s1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
x = input() # Type 001
output = x[::-1] # You obtain what you want: 100
```

Answer (score 1):

The string representation of an integer doesn't include left-side zero-fill by default. But you can achieve this via [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill):

```
x = int(input())  # 1
s = str(x).zfill(3)
s1 = s[::-1]

print(s1)  # 100
```

Alternatively, you can require the input to have the prerequisite zero-fill:

```
x = input()  # 001
s1 = x[::-1]

print(s1)    # 100
```